# Changing directive function dynamically

Tags: angularjs

Given the following directive:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
          return {
            restrict: "AE",        
            scope: {              
                myFunction: '&'
            },

            templateUrl: "some_template.html",
            link: function (scope, element) {
            }
         }
   });
```

I declare it as

```
<my-directive my-function="function1()"></my-directive>
```

But my problem is that in the controller I need to call `function1` or `function2` depending on a condition. Is there a way to dynamically change the function in `my-function` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just set it to some variable instead that references one function or the other:

```
<my-directive my-function="functionToCall()"></my-directive>
```

This `functionToCall` can be changed dynamically as you need:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="functionToCall = function1">Switch to function 1</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="functionToCall = function2">Switch to function 2</button>
```

Check [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7NAZU4y5MC2O08xlNhOB?p=preview) for a working example.